# Using margin percentages relative to a wrapper div not the browser size

Tags: html, css, positioning

I need to position three buttons using css. I am currently using margin-left: 20% for example. However when I change the browser window size the buttons move from their original location.

This is the link to my site: http://www.iamjoetaylor.co.uk

The other elements all stay in the right place, what do I need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"position: absolute" element's coordinates and margins are computed from the closest parent element that had position absolute or relative. If there is no such element, then they are computed from the body element.

If you want to position buttons relatively to #wrapper element, then you need to set #wrapper's position to relative.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `position:absolute` on the 3 divs that contains the element. In my opinion, you should rewrite the rules for those to achieve the style you want using `position: relative`

Answer (score 0):

Setting your margin's to a percentage is relative to the size of the parent element. If the margin require for the bullet list needs to stay consistant regardless of the size of the browser window, simply use `px` instead of `%`